# After random rotation how do you get rotation angle using rotate plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to find the angle where my "spin" object lands while using the google rotate plugin. Here is my code so far:

```
$('#spinnerButton a').bind('click', function(e) {

    var deg = 1500 + Math.round(Math.random()*1500);

    var rotation = function (){

       $("#spinImg").rotate({
          angle:0, 
          animateTo: deg,
          duration: 6000
       });

       console.log (deg);

    }
    e.preventDefault();
    rotation();

});
```

I can get the degrees with which it lands. (high number) But am trying to use .getRotateAngle() to no avail. I've tried a callback set to 7000 and tried just using $(this).getRotateAngle(); but again, nothing shows up other than the original position of "0".

Comment: Isn't your answer always going to be `deg % 360`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[<kbd>jsFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/xJnqM/1551/)

```
  $("#image").rotate({
      bind: {
          click: function () {
              var deg = 1500 + Math.round(Math.random() * 1500);
              $("#image").rotate({
                  angle: 0,
                  animateTo: deg,
                  duration: 6000,
                  callback: function() {
                        alert( $(this).getRotateAngle() % 360 );
                  }
              });
          }
      }
  });
```